# Order a list by a string value with the same name as the property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I don't know how. Could I use what they call reflection?

I want to order the `resultList` by the value in `id` where the id has the same value as the name of the property to order by.

```
var resultList = repository.GetPersons();

// Order the result based on the value in the string id
if (id == "organisation")
    resultList = resultList.OrderBy(p => p.organisation);
else if (id == "surname")
    resultList = resultList.OrderBy(p => p.surname);
else if (id == "lastname")
    resultList = resultList.OrderBy(p => p.lastname);
else if (id == "adress")
    resultList = resultList.OrderBy(p => p.adress);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will surely helps you : [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy using String Names!](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/03/26/Dynamic_LINQ_OrderBy_using_String_Names.aspx)

Class

```
public class Person
{
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Use

```
// First we define the parameter that we are going to use
// in our OrderBy clause. This is the same as "(person =>"
// in the example above.
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");

// Now we'll make our lambda function that returns the
// "DateOfBirth" property by it's name.
var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>>
                       (Expression.Property(param, "DateOfBirth"), param);

// Now I can sort my people list.
Person[] sortedPeople = people.OrderBy(mySortExpression).ToArray();
```

Comment: I actually removed "person" from the expresion: `var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));` But might be useful to keep it here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).